# How to send variable from base ule in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want send id from view to controller. I send by using anchor tag in codeigniter. But id is not send. So please some one help me to send variable using `baseurl`.

My code is like:

```
base_url('controller/function/$id').
```

And how to receive variable in controller?

The complete anchor:

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url('reports/trackemail/$m_id');?>"> Track this Message</a></td>
```

Comment: show the entire anchor tag code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url('reports/trackemail/'.$m_id);?>"> Track this Message</a></td>
```

and in  reports controller

```
function trackemail()
{
    if($this->uri->segment(3))
    {
        echo $this->uri->segment(3);
    }
}
```

please let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do like this in the controller:

```
# in the reports controller
public function trackemail(){
    if($this->uri->segment(3)){
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    }else{
        #do something here or redirect
    }
}
```

In the view

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url('reports/trackemail/'.$m_id);?>">Track this Message</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you pass it like your example, than it goes to the function of controller as a parameter, so you have to catch it in the parameters.

```
  function yourfunction($id){

}
```

you can also add more parameters to it.

Answer (score 1):

NO thing is wrong in question but while recieving data in controller use get method.

Answer (score 0):

To get the id in the controller you need to write a function that should have an input parameter like in your case :

say you are passing 'controllerName/functionName/$id' then function should be in the controller by the name of controllerName and the function should be like

```
function funtionName($id){
// do something
}
```

Comment: i have 4 function index,trackemail etc but i don't have same name of controller.

Comment: i did function funtionName($id){// do something} but not working

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like

```
$this->input->get('id');
```

and also from function parameters like

```
function my_function($id) {
    echo $id;
}
```

Try this [**LINK**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)

Answer (score 0):

## in the reports controller

```
public function yourfunction(){

   if($this->base_url()->segment(3)){

    $id = $this->url()->segment(3);
   }
}
```